# How to extract CSS to a `critical.css` stylesheet via an `import` statement with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, mini-css-extract-plugin

#### Background

Our web application follows a component-based design pattern, with each component containing a template, Sass partial, and JavaScript module, like so:-

```
components/action_button/_action_button.html.erb
                        /_action_button.scss
                        /action_button.js
```

The JavaScript module `import`s the component's Sass partial and the template is rendered via Rails. Webpack is configured with a number of loaders and plugins to compile the styles and extract (via `mini-css-extract-plugin`) the resulting CSS into a standalone stylesheet for each entrypoint e.g.:-

```
home.js => home.js, home.css
search.js => search.js, search.css
```

Components are `import`ed into entrypoints based on usage (i.e. if `action_button` is present on 'home', then it's rendered somewhere within the view and `import '~/components/action_button/action_button.js';` is declared within `home.js`.

#### The Problem

In order to improve the page loading experience we're manually `@import`ing a select few component Sass partials into a `critical.scss` entrypoint, the outputted CSS is then inlined into the `<head>` of the document and the full stylesheets are loaded asynchronously.

Ideally, we'd like to do this dynamically and one method I've thought of is denoting the criticality of a component via the `import` statement. Perhaps using a custom loader?:-

```js
import 'critical-loader!~/components/action_button/action_button.js';
```

The issue is that I've little idea of how that Webpack loader would work. I essentially want it to leave all existing rules in-place, but redirect the extracted CSS from Sass partials `import`ed *from within it* to `critical.css`.

Does anyone know of an existing solution or have any idea of where to begin with a problem like this?